# Variable expansion _not working within a foreach-object loop

Tags: powershell

I have a script that should show me the current logged in user on every machine in my network. But $_ is never expanded. I also tried with single or double quotes ("$*" '$*'). Nothing works as expected.

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter * |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 

$Computers | 
ForEach-Object {
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -name $_ | select USername,Caption,Manufacturer
}
```

I always get this error

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid Namespace 
At Zeile:6 Zeichen:18
+     Get-WmiObject <<<<  win32_computersystem -name $_ | select USername,Caption,Manufacturer
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I seached a lot about variable expansion within Powershell but I found nothinq about nesting commands like this.

**EDIT: my fault. I have to use -comp instead of -name** Now it works.

```
$Computers | 
ForEach-Object {
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -comp $_ | select USername,Caption,Manufacturer
}
```

Comment: What relation between `Get-ADComputer` returned object's `Name` property and `-Namespace` parameter of `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet?

Comment: Or, to put what PetSerAl said a different way, the -Name parameter is actually -NameSpace and allows you to specifiy the NameSpace for a WMI query. Not the Name of a machine which is how you seem to be using it.

Comment: OMG. You both are so right. The right parameter is '-comp' not -name. It was completely my fault.

Answer (score 0):

My fault. I have to use -comp instead of -name. Now it works.